# How to create an empty zip file?

Tags: python, zip

I'm using `zipfile` and under some circumstance I need to create an empty zip file for some placeholder purpose. How can I do this?

I know this:

> Changed in version 2.7.1: If the file is created with mode 'a' or 'w'
>   and then closed without adding any files to the archive, the
>   appropriate ZIP structures for an empty archive will be written to the
>   file.

but my server uses a lower version as 2.6.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create an empty zip file without the need to `zipfile` as:

```
empty_zip_data = b'PK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

with open('empty.zip', 'wb') as zip:
    zip.write(empty_zip_data)
```

`empty_zip_data` is the data of an empty zip file.

Comment: For Python 3 use `empty_zip_data = b'PK\x05...`.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply do:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
archive_name = 'test_file.zip'
with ZipFile(archive_name, 'w') as file:
  pass
```

Comment: Downvoted as this does not produce a readable `ZipFile` (`zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`)

Comment: Works for me on Linux and Windows and on Python 3.8 and Python 3.9. The created zip file is a valid ZIP file in Python and in 7-Zip.

Answer (score 1):

If on Linux:

`echo 504b0506000000000000000000000000000000000000 | xxd -r -p > empty.zip`